# Cursor jumping to the right when onClick, due to removing the thousands separator in React

Tags: reactjs

If the value (a number) is, for example, `1,234` and I click between 2 and 3, the cursor jumps between 3 and 4 as the number is reformated to `1234`, but `cursor` remembers the previous position. `formattedNumber.removeGrouping` removes the thousands separator. How can I fix it, as I need the reformatting?

```
const onClickHandler = (event: any) => {
        const numberString = String(event.target.value);
        if (numberString.length > 0) {
            const number = formattedNumber.parse(numberString, language);
            if (isNaN(number)) {
                return;
            }

            value = formattedNumber.removeGrouping(numberString, language);

            const cursor = event.target.selectionStart;
            const element = event.target;
            window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                element.selectionStart = cursor;
                element.selectionEnd = cursor;
            });

            setValue(value);
        }
    };
```

Comment: You need some way to figure out where `numberString[cursor]` ends up in the reformatted `value`. What is `formattedNumber.removeGrouping` and does it let you figure this out?

Comment: formattedNumber.removeGrouping removes the thousands separator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the solution by my own:

```
const onClickHandler = (event: any) => {
        const numberString = String(event.target.value);
        if (numberString.length > 0) {
            const number = formattedNumber.parse(numberString, language);
            if (isNaN(number)) {
                return;
            }

            // Calculates where to position the cursor
            let cursor = event.target.selectionStart;
            const element = event.target;
            const beforeCursorString = numberString.slice(0, cursor);
            if (beforeCursorString.length > 0) {
                const beforeCursorNoSeparators = formattedNumber.removeSeparators(beforeCursorString, language);
                const diffLength = beforeCursorString.length - beforeCursorNoSeparators.length;
                cursor = cursor - diffLength;
            }
            window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                element.selectionStart = cursor;
                element.selectionEnd = cursor;
            });

            setValue(formattedNumber.removeSeparators(numberString, language));
        }
    };
```